# Appconfig return null value

Tags: c#

Before post my question here,i tried google it and followed different way they suggested still i couldn't able to figure ,here is the simple thing am trying

this is my app config file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        --some code here
    </system.serviceModel>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ServerAddress" value="11.0.0.1" />
        <add key="Port" value="" />
        <add key="Sender" value="" />
        <add key="SenderPassword" value="" />
        <add key="Subject" value="" />
        <add key="AttachmentPath" value="" />
        <add key="Body" value="" />
    </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

Am trying to read this value in my method like below

```
string ftpserverIp = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerAddress"];
```

but ftpserverIp value is shows alway null here,some one please correct me what am missing.

Comment: did you try to match the case?

Comment: Good Job in using Google First!

Comment: yep tried the match case like string ftpserverIp = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerAddress"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out,it was referred other Appconfig file in  my main console application

Comment: How to refer the correct App.Config file in the correct project?